# Can one search a git repo (or github) for recently written code that contains particular text?

Tags: git, github

For example, I'd like to search a particular repo for TODO comments that were committed in the last month.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual. `git log --help`

Answer (score 1):

`git log` has a `--grep` flag to help you search its outcome. Combine it with `-p` to see the contents of the patches and `--since` and you're set to go:

```
$ git log -p --since="1 month" --grep TODO
```

Comment: The `--grep` option is just for searching the commit messages, not the commit contents. I think the TODO are comments in the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log -S`. This option is commonly called [the gitpickaxe](http://www.philandstuff.com/2014/02/09/git-pickaxe.html).

Comment: Worth also mentioning `-G`.

Answer (score 0):

@Code-Apprentice, thanks for the hint. After looking at 10% of the the `git log` help, the best approach seems to be:

```
git log -S TODO --since=2017-10-01 -p . > tmp_file
```

and then I can search `tmp_file` for TODO. That's the quickest way for me to find what I want.